# Is there a variant of list-map in ATS library for processing a segment of a list?

Tags: ats

I am interested in processing a segment of a given list without actually building the segment. I guess this is form of processing in situ.

Comment: Hints? For a linear list, one could define a singly-linked list segment view. Painful, but that should work.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I could do at this moment is to build a linear stream (stream_vt):

```
#include
"share/atspre_staload.hats"
#include
"share/atspre_staload_libats_ML.hats"

fun
{a:t@ype}
streamize_list0_seg
( xs: list0(a)
, i0: intGte(0), n: intGte(0)): stream_vt(a) =
(
stream_vt_takeLte
  (streamize_list0_elt(list0_drop_exn(xs, i0)), n)
)
```

The function `streamize_list0_seg` builds a linear stream for a chosen list segment. Note that only the first node in a linear stream, if exists, can be accessed.